# How to add Custom Elementor Divider widget in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, elementor, divider, custom-widgets

I'm creating a **custom Elementor widget**, I want to add a Vertical line in my widget in between two text. So I have added a Divider control inside the custom widget and this divider should be customized by the User (the width and the height based on their needs).

If I add in the Divider, it is displayed on the left side editor panel and not on the widget (which I'm customizing now)

This is how I'm creating the custom widget in elementor.

Attached the custom widget looks, but I am not getting this kind of widget

[image]